# How to turn post into pages and via versa?

Tags: pages

I made a wordpress blog. Too many pages. I want to convert all of them into posts and maintain all the links. How do I do so?

Comment: try changing the `post_type` from `post` to `page` in the `wp_posts` table in the database... test with one to make sure it doesn't break anything :-)

Comment: there should be a plugin for that